# as_tibble control level of flattening

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, tibble

In the example below I have a list where one element is a list with a sublist. It appears that `as_tibble()` is flattening down until the 3rd level of list before stopping. It would be nice to be able to control the flattening so I could preserve the entire list with sublist in element `"c"` of the example. I suspect some combination of `map()`, `flatten()`, etc. is needed, but cannot figure it out.

#### Issue Reproduced

`as_tibble()` returns 2 rows, but I really only want 1 row with a column corresponding to each list element ("a", "b", "c").

```
library(dplyr)
x <- list(a = 1, 
          b = 2, 
          c = list(x=list(y=3, 
                          z=4), 
                   xx=NULL))
parsed <- as_tibble(x)
parsed
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>       a     b c         
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
#> 1    1.    2. <list [2]>
#> 2    1.    2. <NULL>

parsed[1,]$c
#> $x
#> $x$y
#> [1] 3
#> $x$z
#> [1] 4

parsed[2,]$c
#> $xx
#> NULL
```

#### Desired Behavior where I unnest only the first level

```
parsed <- as_tibble(x)
parsed
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>       a     b c         
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
#> 1    1.    2. <list [2]>

parsed[1,]$c
#> $x
#> $x$y
#> [1] 3
#> $x$z
#> [1] 4
#> $xx
#> NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as.tibble will repeat each column recycle each column value till they all have a shared number of elements. Here you are `a` and `b` have length 1, but `c` has length 2. So it seems you really want to treat it as a length one list, you just need to nest it in a list. I think this will do what you want in this case at least.

```
parsed <- as_tibble(modify_if(x, ~length(.x)>1, list))
```

Comment: That makes sense about reducing to a common length. Your code is nice and compact. Any way to unfurl the length 1 list we had to create to make it work in the first place?

Comment: It needs to be a list in order to be in a tibble. That's just how tibbles work. Each column needs to be a collection of the same length. If that's not what you want, then you don't want a tibble (or a data.frame). Just use a list.

Comment: Why do the lists have to be the same length? A single list can be of length 2 and another list can be of length 4, but that doesn't mean they each aren't lists.

Comment: It's a requirement for tibbles and data frames that each column have the same number of elements in order to have the concept of a "row". So the column itself has to be a list, but it can have child lists with different numbers of elements. But the `length()` of every column needs to be the same. That's just a basic requirement of the data structure. What benefits are you hoping to get by using a tibble rather than a simple list?

Comment: In the example above, the list represents a single observation. Now image I have one thousand observations. I'd like it to be a tibble containing 1000 rows x 3 columns, not a list of length 1000 with sublists. Just for consistency and readability.

Comment: Well, then for consistency and readability your lists in the third column will need to be nested in a list. Same for 1 observation or 1000. Maybe you just want `parsed$c[[1]]` to get extract that row's list? But R only has so many container like structures.

Answer (score 2):

This is not elegant but here is one way to do it.

```
library(purrr)
x <- list(a = 1, 
          b = 2, 
          c = list(x=list(y=3, 
                          z=4), 
                   xx=NULL))

# define a function to preserve the list
unnest_one_level <- function(x){
  if(is.list(x)) list(x) else x
}

res <- x %>% map_dfr(unnest_one_level)
res
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>       a     b c         
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
#> 1    1.    2. <list [2]>

res$c
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$x
#> [[1]]$x$y
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[1]]$x$z
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[1]]$xx
#> NULL
```